# How to Cache images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching

What is the best approach to caching images in asp.net?

Comment: You might want to give a bit more information on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you want, what all things you have tried & if you have tried something, where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: i want to chache image in browser cache.
is is possible?

Comment: Yes - see my answer below - you'll need to configure the server to set a caching policy.

Comment: Thanks Zhaph. I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where do you want to cache them?

If you want users/proxies to cache your site's images, the best way to do that would be to set up the caching in IIS on the folders containing your static content (images/JS/css), with suitable cache-busting strategies in place to ensure that if you do update them the calling clients get the latest versions.

In IIS 6 and below, you can do this by:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Expand the websites until you find your site, and the folder containing your images.
3. Right click on the folder and select properties.
4. Select the HTTP Headers tab.
5. Check "Enable content expiration", and set the cache time in the "Expire after" section.
6. Ok out of all the dialogues.

In IIS 7 you can do this by:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Expand the websites until you find your site, and the folder containing your images.
3. Click on the folder in the section headed "IIS" double click on "HTTP Response Headers".
4. Click on "Set Common Headers..." in the "Actions" pane.
5. Check "Expire Web content", and set the cache time in the "After" section.
6. Ok out of all the dialogues.

Comment: Will it take less time to load images?

Comment: @RushabhMaster - this won't speed up the initial image load, as that will still depend on the size of the images and the bandwidth from your server, but it will speed up any subsequent loads - so things like your site logo, background images, etc. should all come from the browser's cache.

Comment: Thanks @Zhaph-BenDuguid, Is there any way we can cache all images in the first load?

Comment: So this should cache them locally after the initial load. The only reliable way to potentially load them faster on the first load is to use a distributed CDN that serves the content from a node closer to your user - this way any limitations with your servers bandwidth and resources can be mitigated.